# Programmatically alter size of UIImageView without manually changing UIImageView size in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, storyboard

Using Objective-C, NO auto layout.

In Storyboard my UIImageView size is 58 Width, 420 Height. Is there a code that programmatically changes the size of that UIImageView without me changing the size of it manually in storyboard?

Comment: I created everything needed for UIImageView. I want to use the same UIImageView twice only in different sizes. I wrote the code for the original size already but don't know if there's a code that'll change the size of UIImageView without me chasing it in storyboard.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You have two instances of UIImageView or one? You can set the frame of an image view in code saying something like self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height); if you only want to change the size you can say something like self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x,self.imageView.frame.origin.y,newWidth,newHeight);

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x,self.imageView.frame.origin.y,newWidth,‌​newHeight);` as @beyowulf said.
Or use CGRectInset (Returns a rectangle that is smaller or larger than the source rectangle, with the same center point):

```
CGRect CGRectInset ( CGRect rect, CGFloat dx, CGFloat dy );
```

Check this out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectInset